# DataGridView minimum column width

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView in my program with a column set like this:

- Autosizemode : AllCellsExceptHeader
- MinimumWidth : 60 pixels.
- Width : 60 pixels.

The problem is that when there is no rows in the DataGridView, the column appears with a width of approximately 5 pixels (ignoring the MinimumWidth of 60 pixels).

Capture of the small column:

[image]

Is there a way to solve that issue? Thanks.

Comment: This is not the default behavior, so you have something else that's setting or resetting one or more of these properties. If the `DataGridView.DataSource = null`, the Columns width is set to the default `Width` value; if the `Rows` collection is cleared (`DataGridView.Rows.Clerar();`), the default behavior, when a `Column.MinimumWidth` is actually set, is to use this value to resize a Column. Columns that have the default `MinimumWidth = 5px`, will use this default setting. So, your Columns are using the default setting.

Comment: When I click on this 5px column header, it automatically resize to 60 pixels. It's very strange.